# Yocto recipe to install shared libraries dependency issues

Tags: yocto

I have a Yocto recipe that compiles dynamically linked shared libraries that should be added to the rootfs. Compiling and adding them to rootfs works fine, but QA packaging warnings are resulted.

```
S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

do_compile () {
    make
}

do_install () {
    install -m 0755 -d ${D}${libdir}
    oe_libinstall -so libA ${D}${libdir}
    oe_libinstall -so libB ${D}${libdir}
    oe_libinstall -so libC ${D}${libdir}
}

INSANE_SKIP_${PN} = "ldflags"
# RDEPENDS_${PN} = "libB${SOLIBS}"
# RPROVIDES_${PN} = "libB${SOLIBS}"

# FILES_${PN} = "${libdir}/lib*${SOLIBS}"
# INHIBIT_PACKAGE_DEBUG_SPLIT = "1"
# INHIBIT_PACKAGE_STRIP = "1"
```

The warning is the following:

```
WARNING: package do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libC.so.1.0.0 contained in package package requires libB.so, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_package? [file-rdeps]
```

The commented `RDEPENDS_${PN} = "libB${SOLIBS}"` doesn't do anything in any way I tried so far.

How can I solve this problem? I don't want to add `INSANE_SKIP_${PN} += "file-rdeps"`, I want to resolve the dependency problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing but isn't your recipe installing `lib{A,B,C}.so.1.0.0` and they actually need `libX.so` (`objdump -x /usr/lib/libC.so.1.0.0`, what's in `NEEDED`)? In which case, they probably should depend on `libX.so.1.0.0` instead, so fix your Makefile/CMakeLists.
I've never seen nor used `oe_libinstall` before, could you just use `install relative/path/to/libA.so.1.0.0 ${D}${libdir}` instead? Maybe that's `oe_libinstall` doing this weird trick?

Also, you probably don't need your manually crafted do_compile, it's already what the basic do_compile does for you (calling make if there's a Makefile available).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. About do_compile, there are more steps, I just erased them in the question for a simpler view. Regarding the libraries, `readelf -a libC.so | grep NEEDED` shows this:
`0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libB.so]
0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libc.so.6]`
And about manual install, I tried that too, with the same effect:
`install -Dm 0755 ${S}/lib{A,B,C}.so ${D}${libdir}/lib{A,B,C}.so.1.0.0`
`cd ${D}${libdir}`
`ln -sf lib{A,B,C}.so.1.0.0 lib{A,B,C}.so`

Comment: `0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libB.so]`
So, here is the problem? I install libB.so.1.0.0 while it actually wants libB.so?

Comment: Yes that's the issue. Also, technically, you're actually installing a renamed libB.so. Better compile with the versioning in place already instead of "patching" later.
Yocto actually does `objdump` on files to determine their `NEEDED` libraries and is then filling automatically the `RDEPENDS` with packages `RPROVIDES`'ing the `NEEDED` libraries. If the recipe creating said packages is already in `DEPENDS` of the recipe, there won't be any warning because Yocto assumes that's a safe and sane default. If it's not, you'll get a warning telling you you're missing a package in `RDEPENDS`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I solved the issue by modifying the Makefiles to add versions and SONAME to the libraries.